# Can Hacker See My VPN Data If he have my Credentials?

Tags: networking, vpn, security, encryption

I have a little question in my mind related to any VPN. As we all know VPN connect through server with private or public encryption key to share encrypted tunnel.

My Question is If unfortunately my Email and password of VPN get breached from somewhere and Hacker know my username and password then he target me. Can he see my data that goes to server if he has my credentials above.I mean he know my username and password so **Can hacker intercept my connection and decrypt with it with my VPN username and password from which I am connected?** If not then I am curious that how VPN Assign encryption key and Is VPN assigned key to each my device that I am connected separately or same key for all my device (I mean if all my devices is logged in with same ID and Password ?

Edited:Email and password is the encryption key for exchanging information with server or it assigned randomly during establishing connection?

Comment: If the hacker knows what they are doing, then yes, they can get access to your information. Change your Windows and Email and Web passwords to vastly stronger passwords.  Make sure your VPN  and router setups have strong encryption and passwords. Restart your computer and network after all the above.

Comment: Email and password is the encryption key for exchanging information with server or it assigned randomly during establishing connection?

Comment: Advanced VPN normally change the encryption keys with the transmitted packets. You would have to check your own VPN. Nonetheless, change everything if someone has compromised your system.

Comment: No My system is not compromised I just ask for my curiosity. I ask for any future case if i totally don't know that my credential is leak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends **a lot** on the protocol used by the VPN. Even counting just the ones considered "more or less standard" will give you a dozen or so. Almost all enterprise VPN systems use their own proprietary thing. And if you include the various commercial VPN apps, even more.

However, nearly all modern data encryption protocols generate a new "session" key for every connection. Your password *is not* used as the actual key, for various reasons.

Also, *most* modern data encryption protocols nowadays provide what's called "forward secrecy". This basically means that each connection uses DH key exchange (or similar) to derive that session key, ensuring that even if the client's or server's long-term credentials leak, there is no way to use them to somehow "decrypt" a connection that was previously captured.

For example, SSH provides forward secrecy, as does TLS (with ECDHE), as does WireGuard, OpenVPN (in its usual TLS mode), or IPSec (if done right). Even if someone can monitor the SSH connection from outside, knowing your or the server's keys still gives them absolutely nothing.

However, this wasn't always the case. For example, in the old PPTP MPPE protocol, nearly everyone just used MSCHAP authentication for ease of use, and in MSCHAP the keys are derived from your password. (This wouldn't be the case with PEAP though.) So if you used PPTP **and** the attacker was in the position to snoop on your (encrypted) packets, they most likely could decrypt it easily.

And when we're talking about the cheap "$1/month for netflix" kind of VPN apps, well, some of them are good, but you really have to always expect the worst.

Comment: I generally use a NordVPN Ikev2. During setup of Ikev2 I choosen to use EAP-MSCHAP v2 authentication.Can hacker derive encryption key from username and password like PPTP ?

Comment: No, IKEv2 activates encryption earlier (also using DH key exchange if the server is configured right) and doesn't rely on MSCHAP-provided keys at all.